# Spark timestamp format with timezone issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, timestamp

I have code:

```
timestampFormat="yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
```

or

```
timestampFormat="yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
Dataset<Row> inputDataFrame = spark.read()
            .format("CSV")
            .option("timestampFormat", timestampFormat)
            .load(path/file);
```

The value `2022-04-05T08:19:00+00:00` is loaded into the hive table as `05.04.2022 10:19:00`.
There is 2 hours difference. It should be `05.04.2022 08:19:00`. Can someone tell me what kind of format should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set spark sql session timezone like below & rerun the job.

```
--conf "spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC" // Change it your timezone.
```

or

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC") // Change it your timezone.
```